# I need a macro in Word that saves each page of a serial letter individually as PDF

Tags: vba, ms-word

All PDF files are created and saved with the correct name in the correct location, but when I try to open the PDF, I get a message that it does not work because the file is damaged, can you help me so I can open the file?

Thanks in advance.

my script:

```
    Sub SerienbriefOneDoc()
'
' SerienbriefOneDoc Makro
'
'
Dim Dateiname As String
 Dim LetzterRec As Long

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Visible = False

 Const path As String = "G:\Laptop\Volume_D\Lehre\Basislehrjahr\Auftraege\Projektarbeit\WordMakro\Serienbrief\save\"      'Speicherpfad des Resultates
 ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
 LetzterRec = Word.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
 ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord

     With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
         .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
         Do
             If .DataSource.ActiveRecord > 0 Then
                If .DataSource.DataFields("Name").Value <> "0" Then
                     .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                     .SuppressBlankLines = True

                     With .DataSource
                         .FirstRecord = .ActiveRecord
                         .LastRecord = .ActiveRecord

                          DName = path & .DataFields("Name").Value & "_" & .DataFields("Vorname").Value & ".pdf"

                     End With
                        .Execute Pause:=False

                     Set dlgSaveAs = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
                        With dlgSaveAs
                        .Format = wdFormatPDF
                         ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=DName
                         ActiveDocument.Close False
                        End With

                 End If

               End If

             If .DataSource.ActiveRecord < LetzterRec Then
                 .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
             Else
                 Exit Do
             End If
         Loop
     End With
     Application.Visible = True
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [Document.SaveAs2 method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2) you need to specify the second paramater `FileFormat` as `wdFormatPDF` otherwise it will save as word document.

Note that

```
With dlgSaveAs
    .Format = wdFormatPDF
```

will only set the fileformat for the dialog box that let you choose the path and filename. But the `SaveAs2` does not care about that if you don't tell it the correct format too.

Anyway it looks like you don't use the save-as dialog box at all. I think you can safely remove this part

```
Set dlgSaveAs = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
With dlgSaveAs
    .Format = wdFormatPDF

End With
```

and only keep that part there

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=DName, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
ActiveDocument.Close False
```

---

#### What actually happened …

… is that you saved a file `your-file.pdf` with an `.pdf` extension but a Word format document inside. If you rename it to `your-file.docx` it would probably open in Word.